# Trace files/modules loaded when launching python

Tags: python, startup, paraview

I am using Paraview 4.0.1 under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
But I guess the answer to this question does not necessarily requires knowledge specific to Paraview python.

When I load a python prompt at the command line everything "works well":

```
$ pvpython 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from paraview.simple import *
paraview version 4.0.1
>>>
```

But when I load the python shell within the GUI, `from paraview.simple import *` fails, either when automatically (at startup) or explicitly imported:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
from paraview.simple import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/simple.py", line 41, in <module>
    import servermanager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 3157, in <module>
    __initialize()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 3148, in __initialize
    c = Connection(iter.GetCurrentSessionId(), iter.GetCurrentSession())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 1935, in __init__
    _createModules(self.Modules)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 2567, in _createModules
    m.filters = createModule('filters')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 2629, in createModule
    if (prop.GetInformationOnly() and propName != "TimestepValues" ) \
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetInformationOnly'
>>> from paraview.simple import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 2190, in find_module
    if vtkPVPythonModule.HasModule(fullname):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'HasModule'
>>>
```

**How can I trace the different sequence of steps taken by each mode of loading a python shell, so as to identify the source of error?**

In addition to this manifestation, I found two other differences:

1. In the command prompt, `from paraview.simple import *` is not executed automatically, while in the GUI it is. **Where is this set?**
2. In the command prompt, having set `PYTHONSTARTUP=${HOME}/.pythonrc`, which sets `import readline, rlcompleter` (actually, within a `try`-`except` construct), allows for tab completion.
   In the GUI, `.pythonrc` is not read. **Why is this? How can I tell the filename which would be read upon startup if it exists?**

Comment: ParaView 4.0.1 is horribly out of date. 5.4.1 is the last version and quite reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one option which gives some information, I do not know if it is the only/best one.

Setting

```
$ export PYTHONVERBOSE=2
```

(or a different integer for verbosity level [[1](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONVERBOSE)]) gives a lot of info.
Still, I couldn't find the source of error...