# Paraview python: different behaviour at GUI vs. command prompt

Tags: python, startup, paraview

This is a question related to
[Trace files/modules loaded when launching python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457230/trace-files-modules-loaded-when-launching-python)

I am using Paraview 4.0.1 under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I get different behaviour when loading a python prompt:

1. At the command line, where everything "works well".
2. Within the GUI ("python shell"), where `from paraview.simple import *` fails, either when automatically (at startup) or explicitly imported.

Below I add (TL;DR) a comparison of the output obtained with methods 1 and 2 above, at two levels of verbosity.

---

1. **Output (standard verbosity level)**

1.1. At the command prompt:

```
$ pvpython 
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from paraview.simple import *
paraview version 4.0.1
>>>
```

1.2. At a python shell within the GUI:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:33:43) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
from paraview.simple import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/simple.py", line 41, in <module>
    import servermanager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 3157, in <module>
    __initialize()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 3148, in __initialize
    c = Connection(iter.GetCurrentSessionId(), iter.GetCurrentSession())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 1935, in __init__
    _createModules(self.Modules)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 2567, in _createModules
    m.filters = createModule('filters')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 2629, in createModule
    if (prop.GetInformationOnly() and propName != "TimestepValues" ) \
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetInformationOnly'
>>> from paraview.simple import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paraview/servermanager.py", line 2190, in find_module
    if vtkPVPythonModule.HasModule(fullname):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'HasModule'
>>>
```

---

2. **Output (verbosity level 2)**

2.1. At the command prompt:

Posted [here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1511448466222.txt) due to length limitation in SO.

2.2. At a python shell within the GUI:

Python Shell window: Posted [here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1511448621928.txt) due to length limitation in SO.

Output Messages window: Posted [here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1511448805979.txt) due to length limitation in SO.

Comment: Once again, i would suggest switching to a newer version of ParaView.

Comment: @user1416930 - Thanks for your comment. Even if 4.0.1 is out of date, it should work. I was hoping to get some insight into the causes and solutions of the problem.

Comment: If you can try and reproduce the same error with a 5.4.1, then you may have more luck finding a answer